# NERDTreeのlet g:NERDTreeDirArrowsが動作しない

Tags: vim

.vimrcに`let g:NERDTreeDirArrows=0`を記述したのですが、正常に`+|`として表示出来ず、
以下の画像の様になってしまいます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

解決法をご存知の方ご助言をよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

そのオプションは削除されてます:

https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/commit/677a83b2b63fda1c52205acd39973fe1b44e8b54

かわりに、このオプションを使うとよいかと思います。(readmeにありました)

```
" デフォルト
let g:NERDTreeDirArrowExpandable = '▸'
let g:NERDTreeDirArrowCollapsible = '▾'
```

ただ、一文字しか使えないようで、思い通りの見た目にはできなさそうです。Windowsではデフォルトで下記のように設定されるみたいです。

```
let g:NERDTreeDirArrowExpandable = '+'
let g:NERDTreeDirArrowCollapsible = '~'
```